# How to get Vendor ID and Device ID of all PCI Devices?

Tags: linux, pci

I need to get Vendor ID and Device ID of all PCI bus Devices from Linux using C/C++ (inline asm allowed), but I can't even understand from what to start.

Please, give me some pieces of advice or code parts.

Comment: looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908782/in-linux-is-there-a-way-to-find-out-which-pci-card-is-plugged-into-which-pci-sl, couldn't lspci give you these info? Or isn't it already in a folder like /dev?

Comment: Sure, lspci gives me this information, but main idea is to get it by myself.

Comment: either find the code of lspci, as it's open source, or parse its outputs...

Comment: To get it yourself, iterate over the contents of `/sys/bus/pci/devices` (or `/proc/bus/pci`).

Comment: The [busybox lspci.c](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/util-linux/lspci.c) is short enough that we could even post it here.

Comment: The link @B.Go refers to has no answer on `lspci` *(the `lspci -s` from the link does not print PID:VID)*. But for future readers: it turns out the way of fetching this info with `lspci` is two-stage: first you use `lspci` and copy the PCI ID that looks like this `00:02.0`. Then you call `lspci` again upon this ID like this `lspci -ns 00:02.0`. It has to be two-stage, because calling `lspci -n` won't print human-readable names, so you can't figure out which one is the device you're interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get Vendor ID and Device ID of all PCI Devices?

In short, you have to write a C program that does:

```
grep PCI_ID /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/uevent
```

Sample output lines:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/uevent:PCI_ID=1022:14E8
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.2/uevent:PCI_ID=1022:14E9
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/uevent:PCI_ID=1022:14EA
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/uevent:PCI_ID=1022:14EA
```

And extract relevant data after `=` and after `:`.

So what you have to do is:

- iterate over directories in `/sys/bus/pci/devices` with `readdir_r`
- for each directory

  - open the uevent file from inside that directory
  - read lines from the file until `PCI_ID` is found
  - if found
    - basically match the line with `sscanf(line, "PCI_ID=%4x:%4x\n", &vendor_id, &device_id)`

I couldn't find any documentation about `uevent` inside `/sys/bus/pci/devices`. This answer is based on reverse engineering [busybox lspci.c sources](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/util-linux/lspci.c).

Comment: Do I correctly understand, that there are some files, where I can get some additional information about device's header type, I/O Register values, ROM Registers, Class code, etc.?

Comment: Vendor and device IDs are also available separately on `/sys/bus/pci/devices/*/vendor` and `/sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device`.